# Web API project template in VS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Why can't we create WebAPI project directly just like "WCF Service Application" template in VS.I want to create separate solution not using MVC or ASP.Net WebForms template. In our project we intend to have service layer on different physical machine hosted by IIS to be consumed by different web applications.

Comment: This is a question for Microsoft's VS team, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: May be you are right. But i thought there is some rational behind that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET team is in the process of making their offering more cohesive, an effort they call "One ASP.NET."  Under One ASP.NET, MVC, Web Forms, Web API, SignalR, and Entity Framework are all first class citizens.  They want to make it easy to create web applications that utilize these technologies without having to give up the others; that is, you can make an MVC project but still use Web Forms; or a Web Forms project can easily add a Web API Project.

Anyway, back to your question: you can't create a Web API project directly (i.e. it's not in the main project template list) anymore because it has been rolled into the the single ASP.NET project type.

They explain,

> Starting with Visual Studio 2013, the guessing game about which
>   project type to choose is over. There is now only one web project type
>   in Visual Studio.
>
> As you can see from the list of templates, we can choose to start with
>   a standard Web Forms, MVC, or Web API project type. The other project
>   types from the old MVC template dialog are still here. The interesting
>   part is the checkboxes underneath the list of templates. Here, we can
>   choose to add Web Forms references and folders to an MVC project, or
>   MVC references and folders to a Web Forms project. This is the gateway
>   to using more of these features in concert with each other in your
>   project.

[Read the full MSDN blog article about One ASP.NET and the new project types here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2013/11/12/one-asp-net-welcome-to-the-web-development-buffet.aspx)

**You can, however, still create a project (or solution) that contains just the Web API references.**  Just use the ASP.NET project dialog to choose the Web API project type, and make sure all the other check boxes are unchecked.  You'll be able to make your project just for Web API, and then go host it on a dedicated box for your services layer.  It's all still there, the UI just looks a little different.